# No recibo datos que envío a través de xhr.send( );

Tags: javascript, php

Soy muy nuevo en esto de la programación, tengo el siguiente código php:

```
<?php
$idPeriodo = 1; // Establece un valor predeterminado
$idMateria = 20; // Establece un valor predeterminado

// Verifica si se han enviado valores desde JavaScript a través de una solicitud POST
if (isset($_POST['idPeriodo']) && isset($_POST['idMateria'])) {
    $idPeriodo = intval($_POST['idPeriodo']);
    $idMateria = intval($_POST['idMateria']);
    // Las variables $idPeriodo y $idMateria se han actualizado desde JavaScript
    echo "Valor recibido para idPeriodo: " . $idPeriodo;
    echo "Valor recibido para idMateria: " . $idMateria;
} else {
    echo "No se recibió el valor de idPeriodo e idMateria";
}
?>
```

Esto para recibir datos que estoy enviando desde ese mismo archivo php. Cuando elijo una opción en la combo box de periodos y la combo box de materia le asigno un número específico a las respectivas variables, luego esas las utilizo para hacer consultas de una base de datos, pero necesito actualizar el valor de las variables cada que se cambie de opción en una de las combo box, además dependiendo del valor que elija en el periodo así cambiaran las opciones de la combo box de materias a elegir:

```
    <div id="comboContainer">
        <label for="opcionCombo">Selecciona el periodo:</label>
        <select id="opcionCombo">
            <option value="periodo1">Periodo 1</option>
            <option value="periodo2">Periodo 2</option>
            <option value="periodo3">Periodo 3</option>
            <option value="periodo4">Periodo 4</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div id="comboContainer2">
        <label for="opcionCombo2">Materia:</label>
        <select id="opcionCombo2">
            <!-- Este select se llenará dinámicamente con JavaScript -->
        </select>
    </div>

    <?php
    $opcionesPorPeriodo = [
        'periodo1' => [
            ['materia' => "Módulo 3.1", 'idMateria' => 20],
            ['materia' => "Módulo 3.2", 'idMateria' => 21]
        ],
        'periodo2' => [
            ['materia' => "Módulo 3.3", 'idMateria' => 22],
            ['materia' => "Módulo 3.4", 'idMateria' => 23]
        ],
        'periodo3' => [
            ['materia' => "Módulo 3.5", 'idMateria' => 24],
            ['materia' => "Módulo 3.6", 'idMateria' => 25]
        ],
        'periodo4' => [
            ['materia' => "Módulo 3.7", 'idMateria' => 26],
            ['materia' => "Módulo 3.8", 'idMateria' => 27]
        ]
    ];
    ?>
```

Y este es el Script que envía los datos:

```
    <script>
        var opcionesPorPeriodo = <?php echo json_encode($opcionesPorPeriodo); ?>;
        var combo1 = document.getElementById("opcionCombo");
        var combo2 = document.getElementById("opcionCombo2");
        var idPeriodo = <?php echo $idPeriodo; ?>; // Inicializa con el valor predeterminado
        var idMateria = <?php echo $idMateria; ?>; // Inicializa con el valor predeterminado

        // Llenar combo2 basado en la selección de combo1 (al cargar la página)
        window.addEventListener("load", function () {
            combo1.addEventListener("change", actualizarCombo2);

            // Trigger del evento "change" para que se actualice idPeriodo e idMateria al cargar la página
            combo1.dispatchEvent(new Event("change"));
        });

        // Función para llenar combo2 basado en la selección de combo1
        function actualizarCombo2() {
            var periodoSeleccionado = combo1.value;
            var opciones = opcionesPorPeriodo[periodoSeleccionado] || [];
            combo2.innerHTML = ""; // Limpiar opciones anteriores

            for (var i = 0; i < opciones.length; i++) {
                var option = document.createElement("option");
                option.value = opciones[i].idMateria; // Usar idMateria como valor
                option.text = opciones[i].materia;
                combo2.add(option);
            }

            // Actualizar idPeriodo
            idPeriodo = combo1.selectedIndex + 1; // Sumamos 1 porque los índices de opciones comienzan en 0

            // Actualizar idMateria
            var materiaSeleccionada = combo2.value;
            idMateria = materiaSeleccionada;

            // Trigger del evento "change" para que se actualice idMateria
            combo2.dispatchEvent(new Event("change"));

            // Llamar a la función para enviar las variables actualizadas a PHP
            actualizarVariablesEnPHP();
        }

        // Actualizar idMateria cuando se cambia la materia en combo2
        combo2.addEventListener("change", function () {
            var materiaSeleccionada = combo2.value;
            idMateria = materiaSeleccionada;

            // Llamar a la función para enviar las variables actualizadas a PHP
            actualizarVariablesEnPHP();
        });

        function actualizarVariablesEnPHP() {
            // Usa AJAX para enviar las variables actualizadas a PHP en la misma página
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('POST', '', true); // La URL está vacía para que se envíe a la misma página
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

            console.log('Enviando idPeriodo: ' + idPeriodo + ', idMateria: ' + idMateria);

            xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
                    // Aquí puedes procesar la respuesta del servidor si es necesario
                }
            };
            xhr.send('idPeriodo=' + idPeriodo + '&idMateria=' + idMateria);
        }
    </script>
    introducir el código aquí
```

Al parecer no me está recibiendo los datos el 'if' de allá arriba. Si necesitan más datos pregúntenme.

Comment: Para empezar, xhr está un poquito anticuado ya. Lo correcto sería usar [fetch api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API). Por qué afirmas que "no se están recibiendo los datos"? Dónde se supone que usas esos datos para ver que se está recibiendo o no?? Porque dentro del `if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200)` no haces absolutamente nada, y ahí es donde tendrás la respuesta de tu código php. Tu formulario no se va a actualizar solo eh, vas a tener que actualizarlo tú con lo que recibas en JS. PHP está en el servidor, ahora lo estás llamando desde el cliente